# SQL query to filter out XML nodes that has a particular attribute value

Tags: jquery, sql, xml, where-clause

I would like to filter only the nodes where Junk is true in the following XML using SQL query.  What I like to do is what in regular SQL would be like "select * from main where junk=true";

Here is the XML that I would like to query.

```
    <Main>
      <Box>
        <Name>Box1</Name>
        <Junk>false</Junk>
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <Name>Box2</Name>
        <Junk>true</Junk>
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <Name>Box3</Name>
        <Junk>false</Junk>
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <Name>Box4</Name>
        <Junk>false</Junk>
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <Name>Box5</Name>
        <Junk>false</Junk>
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <Name>Box6</Name>
        <Junk>true</Junk>
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <Name>Box7</Name>
        <Junk>true</Junk>
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <Name>Box8</Name>
        <Junk>false</Junk>
      </Box>
    </Main>
```

I tried the following:

```
    declare @main xml;
    declare @junk xml;

    set @main = '';

    set @junk = (select  @main WHERE @main.value('(/Main/Junk)[1]', 'nvarchar(10)')  = 'true');
```

but it always return all the list.

How can I update this query to return only the nodes where Junk = true?

Expected result:

```
    <Main>
      <Box>
        <Name>Box2</Name>
        <Junk>true</Junk>
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <Name>Box6</Name>
        <Junk>true</Junk>
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <Name>Box7</Name>
        <Junk>true</Junk>
      </Box>
    </Main>
```

OR

```
    <Box>
        <Name>Box2</Name>
        <Junk>true</Junk>
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <Name>Box6</Name>
        <Junk>true</Junk>
      </Box>
      <Box>
        <Name>Box7</Name>
        <Junk>true</Junk>
      </Box>
```

Comment: It's depends on which dialect you use PLSQL, PgSQL, TSQL?

Comment: maybe you forgot the **Box** node `/Main/Box/Junk` look [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/-2ni5Q3j)

Comment: I am using SQL.

Comment: @jjdesign, can you add your solution here so I can mark it as the answer? That external link may not work tomorrow, who knows.

Answer (score 1):

in proper t-sql xml that would be

```
SELECT
   x.query('.')
FROM @main.nodes('/Main/Box') a(x) 
WHERE 
      x.value('(Junk)[1]', 'nvarchar(10)')  = 'true'
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('Main')
```